# fragmented mp4 javascript converting

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I wanted to know if there is a way to convert regular mp4 to a fragmented mp4 via javascript. (like mp4box does) Is it efficient enough (not suppose to be a complicated task)? did anyone write something like this?
to make it harder, can it be on the fly? meaning I will not download the whole mp4 from the server but download in parts and convert it into fragments compatible with fragmented mp4 and mpeg-dash  - I'm trying to overcome to problem to not have to use 2 different file types to play a video or do mp4box on all my library in advance.

Regardless, is it possible to convert from h.264 compatible files with different containers (mov, flv etc.) to fragmented without a server? meaning do it in the browser with javascript somehow?

appreciate the help,
Yug

Answer (score 1):

I am working on something similar (which lead me to here) but no clue so far. However, below is my finding:

Broadway:
https://github.com/mbebenita/Broadway

The idea is you may write a C/C++ using FFMPEG source library, then use Emscripten to compile your C/C++ coding into Javascript. I yet start working with this method, not sure this will work or not. If you did do let me know.

Comment: Looking forward to hearing your results.

Comment: sorry about that, I did not go any further from this. I think plugin should be the correct way for my case.